# How to enable serializing for REST applications in ASP.NET Core 8?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0, json-serialization

In my project, the server returns the empty object while I have checked that `this.taskGateway.RetrieveSelection` returns the correct data:

```cs
[ApiController]
public class TaskController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly TaskGateway taskGateway = FrontServerDependencies.Injector.gateways().Task;
  
    [HttpGet(TasksTransactions.RetrievingOfSelection.URN_PATH)]
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<
      ActionResult<TaskGateway.SelectionRetrieving.ResponseData>
    > Get() 
    {
        return base.Ok(
            await this.taskGateway.RetrieveSelection(
                new TaskGateway.SelectionRetrieving.RequestParameters
                {
                    OnlyTasksWithAssociatedDate = onlyTasksWithAssociatedDate,
                    OnlyTasksWithAssociatedDateTime = onlyTasksWithAssociatedDateTime,
                    SearchingByFullOrPartialTitleOrDescription = searchingByFullOrPartialTitle
                })
        );
    }
}
```

AFAIK two things may be missed:

1. Something has not been initialized in the entry point
2. Something has been done wrong in the controller method

I was checking the [official Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio).

No listing of entry point has been posted, so I needed to initialize the ASP.NET Core Web API project and check the `Program.cs`. Nothing related to JSON serializing has been mentioned:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

So, it looks like not the first one.

Checking the controller of the example:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace ASP_DOT_NET_CoreWebAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            }).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

The `Get` method returns the array of the objects.
Again, nothing related to JSON serializing.

Why does this example work while my project - no?

The `TaskGateway.SelectionRetrieving.ResponseData` is:

```cs
struct ResponseData
{
    public required uint TotalItemsCount;
    public required uint TotalItemsCountInSelection;
    public required CommonSolution.Entities.Task[] Items;
}
```

Comment: Should be `return Ok(await ...);`?

Comment: @YongShun, Yes, you right, I have deleted it by mistake when boiled down the code. The actual code is including `base.Ok()`.

Comment: Just curious why you use `struct` in this case? Perhaps try adding the `[Serializable]` attribute, change those fields into properties with `{ get; set; }`, or change it to a `class` type.

Comment: @YongShun AFAIK the `struct`s are intended to be used instead of classes when they have only fields and properties but have no method. The response data or request parameters are exactly this case. But, if understood correctly the `record` concept, maybe it is better to replace the structs with records because the response data or request parameters are immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to#serialization-behavior), these are the serialization behaviors:

- By default, all public properties are serialized. You can specify properties to ignore. You can also include private members.
- By default, fields are ignored. You can include fields.

Hence, change the fields to properties as:

```cs
struct ResponseData
{
    public required uint TotalItemsCount { get; set; }
    public required uint TotalItemsCountInSelection { get; set; }
    public required CommonSolution.Entities.Task[] Items  { get; set; }
}
```